# How to link the form and php regex together?

Tags: php, regex, forms, email

I'm new to php. What I'm trying to do right now is do a email validation form using regular expression. When a user enter something silly to the text field and click submit. It will show the email is invalid. I'm using regular expression to test whether user enter the right format. Can anyone please guide me how to link the php regular expression with the form together ?

```
<form action= " " method = "post">
    <p> Enter your email </p>
    <input type ="text" name ="user_email"/>
    <input type ="Submit" /> 
</form>


<?php 
$email = " abc@gmail.com ";
$regex = "^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$"; 
if (preg_match ($regex, $email )){
        echo $email . "is a valid email";
    }else{
        echo $email. " is an invalid email ";
    }

?>
```

Comment: See the [forms tutorial in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php) then. Also look into [`filter_var()`](http://php.net/filter_var) and FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL instead.

Comment: @who space around email should not be there, trim it before preg_match

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$email = " abc@gmail.com ";
```

to

```
$email = $_POST['user_email'];
```

Then it'll take input from the form. Since you're POSTing data to the script all of the variables you've posted will end up in the superglobal $_POST.

Comment: I'm getting this show on my page                                       Array ['user_email'] The email is invalid . Is that something wrong on my code ? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can link the `$_POST` request in several ways, for example:

```
$email = $_POST['user_email'];
```

Also, `preg_match` needs a beginning and ending delimiter to function properly:

```
$regex = "/^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$/";
```

Result:

```
 abc@gmail.com  is an invalid email
```

Example:

**http://ideone.com/igphq1**